# Download file using Rx (reactive programming)

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Currently I'm using this code in order to get a file:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += webClient_DownloadProgressChanged;
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(webClient_ProgressCompleted);
```

I've been taking a look on documentation in order to figure out how to turn this code out using Rx.

I've kicked off creating an `Observable` using `FromEvent` in order to watch out `DownloadFileCompleted` event.

```
Observable.FromEvent<?>(?, ?)
```

Nevertheless, I'm not able to figure how to fill these `?`.

Could somebody get me an example?

Up to now, I've tried with:

```
Observable.FromEvent<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(?1:addHandler, ?2:removeHandler).
```

Nevertheless, .net is requesting me that `?1:addHandler` and `?2:removeHandler` are `Action<Action<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>>` (what's that)?

Comment: Why do you need RX here?

Comment: We want to use `Rx`.

Comment: @tym32167, Rx is about composition. It seems that Jordi is just looking for create one of the building blocks that *may* end up in an Rx pipeline.

Comment: @LeeCampbell got it, thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These overloads are so tricky, I have to [look them up every time](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#FromEvent). I've included some sample subscription code to get you started:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
var progressChangedObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs>(
    h => webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += h,
    h => webClient.DownloadProgressChanged -= h
);

var downloadCompletedObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<AsyncCompletedEventHandler, AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(
    h => webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += h,
    h => webClient.DownloadFileCompleted -= h
);

progressChangedObservable
    .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs)
    .Subscribe(dpcea =>  Console.WriteLine($"{dpcea.ProgressPercentage}% complete. {dpcea.BytesReceived} bytes received. {dpcea.TotalBytesToReceive} bytes to receive."));

downloadCompletedObservable
    .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs)
    .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("Download file complete."));

var dummyDownloadPath = @"C:\temp\temp.txt";
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(@"http://google.com"), dummyDownloadPath);
```

---

**EDIT:**

Per @Enigmativity's suggestion, it is possible to do all this code in a functional style, which also handles cleaning up all the `IDisposable`s. However, I don't find it as readable, and as such wouldn't recommend it:

```
    Observable.Using(() => 
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
        return webClient;
    }, webClient =>
    Observable.Using(() => 
        Observable.FromEventPattern<DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs>(
                h => webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += h,
                h => webClient.DownloadProgressChanged -= h
            )
            .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs)
            .Subscribe(dpcea => Console.WriteLine($"{dpcea.ProgressPercentage}% complete. {dpcea.BytesReceived} bytes received. {dpcea.TotalBytesToReceive} bytes to receive.")),
        sub1 => Observable.Using(() =>
            Observable.FromEventPattern<AsyncCompletedEventHandler, AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(
                    h => webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += h,
                    h => webClient.DownloadFileCompleted -= h
                )
                .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs)
                .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("Download file complete.")),
            sub2 => webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(@"http://google.com"), @"C:\temp\temp.txt").ToObservable()
        )
    )
)
    .Subscribe(_ => {} ); //Subscription required to trigger nested observables
```

Comment: Thanks @Shlomo. Nevertheless, I don't quite to figure out how to use each observable with a `WebClient wc`... Could you add some helping stuff code?

Comment: Added some sample subscriptions.

Comment: I wrote the book, and I too have to look them up every time. However for quick hacks, good old `Observable.Create` can be easier to use.

Comment: Rx team should publish extension library for common BCL objects exposing events as observables. Just like ReactiveUI does.

Comment: Ahh it is open source, so feel free to make the fix.  Thr Rx Team is us, all of us.

Comment: @Shlomo - You really should use `Observable.Using` with `WebClient`.

Comment: I know it sounds selfish, but I want this kind of project to be maintained by MS.

Comment: I hope you are aware that Brenon and Oren dont work for Microsoft. If you dont contribute, then who will. The whole "Rx team" have moved on. Rx was written in 2007-2011 that is 10yrs ago dude

Comment: @Enigmativity, Edited to show alternative with `Observable.Using`. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Huh, I actually thought that there is someone at Microsoft who still maintains RX... In this case you're right, community should step in. Maybe create a tool that would generate sources from given assemblies. Can't imagine doing everything by hand.

Comment: @Shlomo - Why don't you recommend it?

Comment: @Enigmativity Readability is important. It's nice to contain everything in one statement that cleans up all resources, but imagine having to update that code a year after someone else wrote it.

Comment: @Shlomo - It's `IDisposable` so my feeling is that you have to write it that way. There are other ways to make it readable.

Comment: Thanks for all. Is there someway to add some parameters on `webClient` using this functional approach (`webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");`)?